# Django csv error and best place to write business logic

Tags: python, django

**EDIT:**

Q1 is solved by adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  to the form template. Please comment on Q2.

**Qn1:** I get the below error when try to read a csv file, which is uploaded through Forms. Exception may be at this line.

```
records = csv.reader(f)
```

Not sure what to pass . Please see the code below.

**Qn2:** Is it ok to do the csv processing in the model (the csv is for uploading domain data, hence validate/and persist as domain objects). I am new to Django/Python, and most of the example I see so far has not much method in models. This is bit different from what I used to where you capture all the business logic associated with the model in it. Wonder the idiomatic usage in django.

### Exception:

```
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument 1 must be an iterator
```

### View:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            w = Testme()
            w.importCsv(form.cleaned_data["file"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('setup.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### Form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

### Model:

```
class Testme(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    ctu = models.IntegerField()
    address = UsAddress

    def importCsv(self, f):
        records = csv.reader(f)
        for line in records:
            logger.debug(line)
```

Comment: Why did you write method `importCsv` in models class? BTW, you should use `request.FILES['file']`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the file straight from the `request.FILES` object.

```
w.importCsv(request.FILES['file'])
```